# SCP Plugin for QGIS 3.16.7 Error 'raster is not loaded'

Tags: qgis, classification, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, scp

This is more of a FYI than a question...
I'm running SCP (semi automatic classification) 7.10.4  plugin to QGIS 3.16.7 under Windows.
I struggled quite a bit with the following roadblock:

1. Create a band set, successfully
2. Attempt to save a training input set and get the following message:
   Information [4]: Select a raster; raster is not loaded

I spent a few hours trying to figure this one out. I did get it to work once, so I knew it wasn't my installation. I finally came to the conclusion that SCP was having issues with my imagery, which was 3 band visible transformed into Lab colour space (3 bands). This imagery contains negative values and 'weird' ranges. When looking at the stats, GQIS can't make sense of the data either, so I'm going to transform the values. In my investigations, I was able to get the SCP to handle:

1. 3 band imagery (some classification methods are appropriate)
2. floating point imagery (makes sense, most reflectance would be float)
3. other 'drone' multispectral imagery (4-6 bands).

I just wanted to pass this on to perhaps save someone else some time?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. We use a Focused question/Best answer model. While it's acceptable to answer your own question, it is against policy to place the answer in the Question.

Answer (score 0):

First select the target raster(s) in the bandset and go-ahead.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).